# RStudio AWS EC2 error when installing packages dependent on gsl

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio, rstudio-server

I set up an AWS EC2 instance of RStudio using the AMI provided by [Louis Aslett](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/).

However, when i try to install the package "topicsmodels" or "gsl" i get the following errors:

```
> install.packages("gsl")
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gsl_1.9-10.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 172529 bytes (168 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 168 KB

* installing *source* package ‘gsl’ ...
** package ‘gsl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gsl-config... no
configure: error: gsl-config not found, is GSL installed?
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gsl’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gsl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gsl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpBItbU2/downloaded_packages’
```

and

```
> install.packages("topicmodels")
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/topicmodels_0.2-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 712766 bytes (696 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 696 KB

* installing *source* package ‘topicmodels’ ...
** package ‘topicmodels’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c cokus.c -o cokus.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c common.c -o common.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ctm.c -o ctm.o
ctm.c:29:25: fatal error: gsl/gsl_rng.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'ctm.o' failed
make: *** [ctm.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘topicmodels’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/topicmodels’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘topicmodels’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpBItbU2/downloaded_packages’
```

My knowledge of linux and RStudio server edition is fairly limited. I've tried following some intsructions from others who've experienced a similar problem, but none have worked (or i am unable to follow the instructions).

Answer (score 0):

After googling a while this did work for me:

In Ubuntu to get topicmodels to install I needed to make sure that both:

1. GNU Scientific Library(GSL) -- binary package
2. GNU Scientific Library(GSL) -- development pacakage

were installed.